# LDAPS - forcing what client certificate gets presented first

Tags: ssl, ldap, certificate, client

Hey everyone and thanks in advance for any feedback you might have on this.

Got a web application that is trying to authenticate an AD user via LDAPS. The application server in this case being the client and a DC with LDAPS being the server, during TLS handshake, client certificate authentication is requested by the DC and this process takes quite a long time to complete as it seems it is trying to iterate over each certificate that has "Client Authentication" enabled (and there are quite a few of them to go over).

Is there any way on the client (the web app server running Windows) to "force" or "suggest" what certificate gets presented first? If not, is there any way on the server (the DC with LDAPS enabled) to specify that the server only wants to see certificates from a specific CA?

I have had a look into TLS negotiation documentation and so far was not able to find an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The [LdapConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapconnection?view=netframework-4.8) class has a *SessionOptions* property allowing to set a handler named [QueryClientCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.protocols.ldapsessionoptions.queryclientcertificate?view=netframework-4.8#System_DirectoryServices_Protocols_LdapSessionOptions_QueryClientCertificate) which can then return a certificate to use.